# htacess redirect with long query string

Tags: redirect

In Google Webmaster tools, crawl errors keep popping up regarding a long query string.  For example:

```
E-mail.shtml?guid=ARzIOgEPTVO6KO2mCJdr/jPJSdvMPR+KrhWmMFiXgY7Mvk3T+iuKlmAbFyRw8FzFEuMCnZBpzVfQuuC0AiFh25UVPQ7QbQkZDuU+pRlTSjPCgYZWB7oP7P3FcNLG2w0hZWkitncEdpVfuWnVdCvqRqxMwakAtfJRwm03fI/Ye6w
```

I have a redirect for `E-Mail.shtml` to the new page (`contact.html`), but have not found a way to redirect all pages, regardless of the string following the `.shtml`.  The old `E-Mail.shtml` file is not in a folder that I can direct either. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `....shtml`? WTF? Thought that dog has been dead for at least two decades!

Comment: By what means did you implement that redirection?

Comment: First, .shtml was not my idea.  I'm no longer using it.  Second, the current redirect is simply  "Redirect /Email.shtml https://www.PAGE.com/contact.html"